# svn diff on windows vs linux

Tags: linux, windows, svn, diff, line-endings

I have two checkouts of an SVN repository, one on a Windows machine, and one on a Linux machine. The exact same modification is made to both repositories. I then run `svn diff` on both to generate 2 patch files. I expect these two patch files to be identical, but they are not. The reason is that `svn diff` on Windows generates a file with carriage returns.

What is the easiest way to modify the behavior of `svn diff` on Windows to match that of `svn diff` on Linux?

Comment: Run the output through a filter that removes the carriage returns?

Comment: Does `svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style` help at all?

Comment: To be clear, the local files themselves might have some lines with carriage returns and some without.

Comment: @GregHewgill That would either demand applying the same filter on the Linux side, or changing the underlying files to have uniform line endings. Neither option is on the table for me.

Comment: @nanny Nope, those extra options do not change the generated patch file.

Comment: @dshin: Oh, I thought you were just talking about the line endings that appear in the resulting diff file. You might want to clarify your question if you're talking about the line endings in the actual repository files.

Comment: @GregHewgill I am not talking about the actual repository files.

Comment: Then I'm not quite understanding your objection. If `svn diff` creates files with LF endings on Linux, and CRLF endings on Windows, then removing the CR from the diff output files on Windows should make them the same as the Linux files, no?

Comment: If the actual repository files contain CR's, then `svn diff` Linux output will contain CR's, while a CR-filtered `svn diff` Windows output will not.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?  The patch file generated in windows should work in linux as is...  You could always use cygwin, git bash, etc and run svn from there to get your matching diff files if it's really that important.

Comment: @Foosh I downloaded cygwin and ran svn diff with --diff-cmd specified. This did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the exact same output on Windows as you would on Linux you can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and run svn from that instead of the normal command prompt.  This will use a linux-esque version of svn which will generate the patch file with unix line endings while maintaining the line endings of the source file.